# pgftools coordinate date issues in addplot

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I don't understand the place of the rectangle : I was thinging that I must start after the red line

I seem to be 24hours in past.

red line abciss is `axis cs:2021-06-03 00:00`

rectangle begin at `axis cs:2021-06-03 12:00`

Version :

- pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20
- \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}


\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[date coordinates in=x, grid,
    width=\linewidth,
    xticklabel style= {rotate=45,anchor=near xticklabel},
    ]
    \addplot [smooth, mark=*] table [x, y=partiel,] {
      date ok partiel
      2021-06-18 74.17 77.50
      2021-06-17 47.92 73.28
      2021-06-16 79.18 81.57
      2021-06-15 78.49 80.64
      2021-06-14 76.25 79.24
      2021-06-13 80.98 83.57
      2021-06-12 35.82 39.63
      2021-06-11 51.28 51.96
      2021-06-10 79.49 81.57
      2021-06-09 80.23 82.45
      2021-06-08 80.20 82.16
      2021-06-07 75.52 78.27
      2021-06-06 82.20 84.80
      2021-06-05 34.53 38.49
      2021-06-04 75.20 78.64
      2021-06-03 49.01 75.37
      2021-06-02 74.34 82.34
      2021-06-01 16.74 19.38
      2021-05-31 3.44 4.01
  };
  \draw[draw=black, fill=black!40, opacity=.75]
  (axis cs:2021-06-03 12:00, 0) rectangle (axis cs:2021-06-05 12:00, 100);

  \draw[draw=red,] (axis cs:2021-06-03 00:00, -10) -- (axis cs:2021-06-03 00:00, 100);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know why, but your backward plot messes with the way PGFPlots calculates the x-value from the date time. Sorting the date corrects the plot:

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[date coordinates in=x, grid,
    width=\linewidth,
    xticklabel style= {rotate=45,anchor=near xticklabel},
    ]
    \addplot [smooth, mark=*] table [x, y=partiel,] {
      date ok partiel
      2021-05-31 3.44 4.01
      2021-06-01 16.74 19.38
      2021-06-02 74.34 82.34
      2021-06-03 49.01 75.37
      2021-06-04 75.20 78.64
      2021-06-05 34.53 38.49
      2021-06-06 82.20 84.80
      2021-06-07 75.52 78.27
      2021-06-08 80.20 82.16
      2021-06-09 80.23 82.45
      2021-06-10 79.49 81.57
      2021-06-11 51.28 51.96
      2021-06-12 35.82 39.63
      2021-06-13 80.98 83.57
      2021-06-14 76.25 79.24
      2021-06-15 78.49 80.64
      2021-06-16 79.18 81.57
      2021-06-17 47.92 73.28
      2021-06-18 74.17 77.50
  };
  \draw[draw=black, fill=black!40, opacity=.75]
  (axis cs:2021-06-03 12:00, 0) rectangle (axis cs:2021-06-05 12:00, 100);
  \draw[draw=red,] (axis cs:2021-06-03 00:00, -10) -- (axis cs:2021-06-03 00:00, 100);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Date time graph]

**Edit:**

The first date encountered is used as `date ZERO` (p.392 in the manual). This means that when the highest date is seen first as in the reverse plot, all other dates are in a way negative. The correct result can be achieved by setting `date ZERO` explicitly:

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, /pgfplots/date ZERO=2021-05-31}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[date coordinates in=x, grid,
    width=\linewidth,
    xticklabel style= {rotate=45,anchor=near xticklabel},
    ]
    \addplot [smooth, mark=*] table [x, y=partiel,] {
      date ok partiel
      2021-06-18 74.17 77.50
      2021-06-17 47.92 73.28
      2021-06-16 79.18 81.57
      2021-06-15 78.49 80.64
      2021-06-14 76.25 79.24
      2021-06-13 80.98 83.57
      2021-06-12 35.82 39.63
      2021-06-11 51.28 51.96
      2021-06-10 79.49 81.57
      2021-06-09 80.23 82.45
      2021-06-08 80.20 82.16
      2021-06-07 75.52 78.27
      2021-06-06 82.20 84.80
      2021-06-05 34.53 38.49
      2021-06-04 75.20 78.64
      2021-06-03 49.01 75.37
      2021-06-02 74.34 82.34
      2021-06-01 16.74 19.38
      2021-05-31 3.44 4.01
  };
  \draw[draw=black, fill=black!40, opacity=.75]
  (axis cs:2021-06-03 12:00, 0) rectangle (axis cs:2021-06-05 12:00, 100);
  \draw[draw=red,] (axis cs:2021-06-03 00:00, -10) -- (axis cs:2021-06-03 00:00, 100);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```